QuadriFlow: The mesh needs to be manifold and have face normals that point in a consistent direction
Im trying to use Remesh>Quad>Quadriflow Remesh on a model i made and imported to Blender from CLO3D, when i try it appears the phrase "QuadriFlow: The mesh needs to be manifold and have face normals that point in a consistent direction", ive tried different tutorials but none seem to work.


Manifold (put simply) means you dont have any verts, faces or edges that overlap, connect strangely, or are disconnected. "Good geo" essentially. Face normals are which way each polygon is facing. They all have to point in a consistent direction. You need to clean up the mesh before it can remesh it.

Try Mesh > Merge > By distance to get rid of doubled verts, Shift+N to recalculate normals, then do select > Non-Manifold then delete selected faces to see if that helps. Also Mesh > cleanup > delete loose couldn't hurt as well.
